# use a single layout xml file for an activity?

Tags: android, listview, layout

Is it possible to use a single xml file for the "whole layout" (activity)?
Can you "embed" the row layout, that is in a separate file, to the listview in the main layout xml?

So it look something like this

```
<LinearLayout>
  ...
  <ListView>
     <LinearLayout>
       <ImageView>
       <TextView>
       ...
     </LinearLayout>
   </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

If it is possible, how is it done, how do you use "id", adapter etc then?

Because you could use

```
<listview>
...
</listview>
```

and not only

```
<listview .../>
```

...I thought it maybe could be possible to put the row layout directly there inside, but dont know how to do, to get it to work if it is possible. Is it?

Would like to have one single layout xml file, per activity, instead of many small parts. Would be easier to get the whole picture then I think and simplify stuff. Any other ways to do achieve this maybe?

Comment: I'd say foo_content.xml, foo_list_item.xml, quux_content.xml, quux_list_item.xml which is not too bad when sorted alphabetically imho.

Comment: that could be a good step. But sees know that, that sentence about organize files was not so good. Thinks it would be easier generally to have all in one file instead of needing to go through many files to get the "picture" and more.

Answer (score 1):

Its definitely possible to use single xml for listview and its cell layout

It will go like this

You are creating two layouts in xml

`<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/listview_layout"`
`android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"`
`android:orientation="vertical">`

`<ListView android:id="@+id/listview"`
`android:layout_width="match_parent"`
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>`

`</LinearLayout>`

`<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/cell_layout"`
`android:layout_width="fill_parent"` 
`android:layout_height="fill_parent"`
`android:orientation="vertical">`

`.............do your cell layout here`

`</LinearLayout>`

Here use listview_layout for setting your ContentView

`setContentView(listview_layout)`

and use cell_layout in any adapter to set cell layout

you will find good tutorials for setting custom adapters for listview on StackOverFlow

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: I dont follow you, having a new linearlayout block after the first (that is closed with its end "tag") will get an error in eclispe.